# how to upload video with variable to server?

Tags: java, php, android, video

i can get my video to upload to my server fine but when i want to upload it with a variable to use in the PHP then it wont work. I am i doing something wrong? What can i do to upload a variable and then a video so i can name the video what ever is in the variable!

Android code:

```
try{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
    URL url = new URL(UploadVideo_URL);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    OutputStream OS = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));

    String data = URLEncoder.encode("ProductAccountName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ProductOwnerEmail, "UTF-8") + "&" +
            URLEncoder.encode("ProductName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ProductName, "UTF-8");

    bufferedWriter.write(data);
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    bufferedWriter.close();
    OS.close();

    InputStream IS = conn.getInputStream();
    IS.close();

    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
    conn.setRequestProperty("myFile", selectedPath);
    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

    fileInputStream.close();
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "Product upload failed";
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$ProductOwnerEmail = $_POST['ProductOwnerEmail'];
$Productname= $_POST['Productname'];

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['myFile']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['myFile']['type'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];

    $location = "/var/www/html/ProductVideos/$ProductOwnerEmail/" . $Productname;//$NewDirectory . '/' . $file_name;

    move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location);
}
?>
```

error log:

```
03-23 21:34:10.531 15083-15491/com.wilsapp.wilsapp W/System.err:   java.io.IOException: closed
03-23 21:34:10.531 15083-15491/com.wilsapp.wilsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:196)
03-23 21:34:10.531 15083-15491/com.wilsapp.wilsapp W/System.err:     at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
03-23 21:34:10.531 15083-15491/com.wilsapp.wilsapp W/System.err:     at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(DataOutputStream.java:156)
03-23 21:34:10.531 15083-15491/com.wilsapp.wilsapp W/System.err:     at com.wilsapp.wilsapp.SellerHomePage$ProductUpload.doInBackground(SellerHomePage.java:910)
03-23 21:34:10.531 15083-15491/com.wilsapp.wilsapp W/System.err:     at com.wilsapp.wilsapp.SellerHomePage$ProductUpload.doInBackground(SellerHomePage.java:740)
03-23 21:34:10.531 15083-15491/com.wilsapp.wilsapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
03-23 21:34:10.532 15083-15491/com.wilsapp.wilsapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-23 21:34:10.532 15083-15491/com.wilsapp.wilsapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
03-23 21:34:10.532 15083-15491/com.wilsapp.wilsapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
03-23 21:34:10.532 15083-15491/com.wilsapp.wilsapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
03-23 21:34:10.532 15083-15491/com.wilsapp.wilsapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-23 21:34:10.575 776-1345/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@80a63f attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@5bc159
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: You say it won't work.. what exactly does that mean? What happens instead?

Comment: i updated the question with the error log!